# Custom UIViewController transition - Like today tab of appstore app of iOS 11

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller

What is the best way to create a custom `UIViewController` transition that on the first `VC` for example there is an image, and when you tap on it, it rises to the top of the screen and some other UI components (like labels and textViews) are added to the screen?

I want to achieve something like what Apple did on the new "Today" tab on the App Store:

[image: Example]

Any idea what the best way is?

Thank you :)

Comment: Hi F.SO7, Found any solution?

Answer (score 13):

I would go with the native `UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning`, `UIPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition`, etc. ways, where you control all animations/transitions in `func animateTransition(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning)`.

https://github.com/aunnnn/AppStoreiOS11InteractiveTransition

[image: preview]

Hide the destination view and the tapped cell during the animation. Create a new card content view that looks exactly the same as the card cell, and use it for animation instead.

For the animation, you can make it look smooth (e.g., labels moving while background image expanding) by **animating AutoLayout constraints**. Pin all those labels around the card's corners, then as you animating width and height constraints of the card view, it sticks throughout the animation.

Make `contentMode` of the background image view as `.center` to make it stay still (resize it first).

For the content (e.g., text view) *revealing* part, you can snapshot the whole destination view (before hiding it!), and add that below the card view you use for animation. Again, pin left, top, right of the content snapshot to the card view, but use fixed height anchor so that the content shows up just under the card. Ideally, you should have a container to hold a card and this snapshot.

For the blur effect, add the UIVisualEffect with UIBlurEffect under the card and animate its alpha together.

The `cornerRadius` is animatable now, so that's easy. Set the animating card view's cornerRadius to match the original cell, animate it to zero.

There are more details that are better explained in code:

https://github.com/aunnnn/AppStoreiOS11InteractiveTransition

*This repo includes both presenting animation and interactive dismissing parts. It's not exactly the same though.*

Or if you like check out [my article.](https://medium.com/@aunnnn/making-app-store-today-ios-11-custom-transition-part-1-presentation-9e4ef99e75d3)

---

### Extra: Bouncing upward animation

At first, I thought the animation can be done by simply animating edges of a card view to fill the window using `UIView.animate(withDuration: delay: usingSpringWithDamping: initialSpringVelocity: options: animations:`, but I was wrong. The animation doesn't look quite the same as the original if you simply use spring animation on the edges.

**To make the animation as close as the App Store's version as possible**, you should *separate the vertical spring animation from the card expanding animation*. It means you will have *a special container view* to hold `animatingCardView` again. While you animate width and height constraints of `animatingCardView` inside that container with a linear curve, you animate the whole container to the destination vertically with spring animation.*

Answer (score -10):

The picture you have shown above is opening the dialogue.
You can do this in the same way just create the Modal and add all the stuff in it like text, label, image and a cross button. 
Open this dialogue on tap of image

Comment: your answer is not clear! I mean it is not understandable what you are saying. And it seems more likely comment instead of answer!

Comment: answer edited if this can help please have a look at

Comment: The question is how do I animate it to be presented like on the example above. If I present it modally (`self.present(myVC, animated: true, completion: nil)`) it'll be presented from the bottom of the screen to the top.

Comment: Do you have any idea?